# Wait for rgbif download to complete before proceeding

Tags: r, ropensci

I am developing a small application in R Shiny. Part of the application will need to query GBIF to download species occurrence data. This is possible using `rgbif`. The function `rgbif::occ_download()` will download the data and `rgbif::occ_download_meta()` will check whether GBIF has fulfilled your request. For example:

```
geometry <- "POLYGON((30.1 10.1,40 40,20 40,10 20,30.1 10.1))"
res <- occ_download(paste0("geometry within ", geometry), type = "within", format = "SPECIES_LIST")
occ_download_meta(res)

<<gbif download metadata>>
  Status: RUNNING
  Format: SPECIES_LIST
  Download key: 0004089-190415153152247
  Created: 2019-04-25T09:18:20.952+0000
  Modified: 2019-04-25T09:18:21.045+0000
  Download link: http://api.gbif.org/v1/occurrence/download/request/0004089-190415153152247.zip
  Total records: 0
```

So far, so good. However, the following function `rgbif::occ_download_get()` can't download the data for downstream analysis until `occ_download_meta(res)` has completed (when Status = SUCCEEDED).

How can I make the session wait until the download from GBIF has been completed? I  cannot hard code a wait time into the script as different sized extents will take GBIF longer or shorter amounts of time to process. Also, the number of other active users querying the service could also alter wait times. I therefore need some sort of flag where Status == Succeeded before proceeding.

I have copied some skeleton code with comments below.

```
library(rgbif)

geometry <- "POLYGON((30.1 10.1,40 40,20 40,10 20,30.1 10.1))" # Define boundary
res <- occ_download(paste0("geometry within ", geometry), type = "within", format = "SPECIES_LIST")

# WAIT HERE UNTIL Status == SUCCEEDED
occ_download_meta(res)

x <- occ_download_get(res, overwrite = TRUE) # Download data 
data<-occ_download_import(x) # Import into R
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rgbif maintainer here. You could do something like we have within the `occ_download_queue()` function:

```r
res <- occ_download(paste0("geometry within ", geometry), type = "within", format = "SPECIES_LIST")
still_running <- TRUE
status_ping <- 3
while (still_running) {
  meta <- occ_download_meta(res)
  status <- meta$status
  still_running <- status %in% c("succeeded", "killed")
  Sys.sleep(status_ping) # sleep between pings
}
```

you probably want to check for succeeded and killed, and do something different if killed

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for the reply. I'm not quite sure how your code works. I was expecting the R session to hang/wait (blinking cursor) until the file from GBIF is ready for download. When I run the above, the while loop competes almost instantaneously and the session is then free to continue (without the GBIF file having been downloaded).

Comment: that download linked to your account is probably already prepared, so running the above code would complete quickly. the while loop is only to check if it's ready, after the while loop you could then download it, or not download if the status was "killed". you could put the call to download the data within the while loop if you like, up to you

Comment: I think I needed to include 'FALSE' like so: while(still_running==FALSE){ ...}

Comment: I changed this `still_running <- status %in% c("PREPARING", "RUNNING")` which causes the loop to iterate when preparing/running. The loop stops successfully when completed. Thanks for your help!

Comment: note that `occ_download_queue` can be used to handle 1 or more queries, and handles waiting for them to be ready - then you can download/import. Working on a related fxn in rgbif that you can instead pass  in result of occ_download calls